# dynamic switching of two styles.css file in one angular application

Tags: css, angular

I have to merge two angular applications into one major angular application. Hence, now i am having two styles.css files in one angular application. On running this application after merging both, css is going completely for the angular application.

Is there any way by which we can call this two style.css files dynamically depending on the requirement? Or I need to check each class one by one?

Comment: Check if you can achieve it with **[CSS Variables](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_variables.asp)**

Comment: Are you using angular 1.x. or anything above 2.x? If you are using 2.x. and above, by saying you merged two applications into one, do you mean you have two projects configured inside your angular.json?

Comment: one application was build in angular 4 and second is in angular 7. now i need to merge this due to business requirement.

Comment: there is only one project configured in angular.json. just merged the html ans css part

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use two different layouts, each one is a component, so each one has a different set of styles. That it's really easy wit angular router.

In your routing module:

```
// Layout 1
  {
    path: '',
    component: Layout1Component,
    children: [
      { path: 'pageL1_1', component: PageL1_1Component },
      { path: 'pageL1_2', component: PageL1_2Component }
    ]
  },

  // Layout 2 routes goes here here
  {
    path: '',
    component: Layout2Component,
    children: [
      { path: 'pageL2_1', component: PageL2_1Component },
      { path: 'pageL2_2', component: PageL2_2Component }
    ]
  },
```

In your app.component.html:

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

The layouts templates has to include the  element to in order to show child navigation componets.

**IMPORTANT**: Each layput controller should disable view encapsulation so styles applies ti child components:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-layout_1',
  templateUrl: './layout_1.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./layout_1.component.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class Layout1Component implements OnInit {
...
}
```

Comment: hi i have just merged the html and css part.and one application is build in angular 4 version which i need to merge with application build in angular 7 version.